# join a table with itself

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Purpose:

in table 'Reservations' a row represent a ressource that is booked.
rows could share a 'reservation ID'. So if you booked some food and a room, that would be two rows sharing the same reservation ID.

Now using lambda expressions. if one of these rows have a special boolean set 'lets call it externBoolean' if this is true. I want to get that row and the other rows that have the same reservation ID.
Then return a list with all the rows that has true in this boolean and all the sibling rows.

basicly something like this:

```
select t2.*
from Reservations t1
join Reservations t2
on t1.ReservationId = t2.ReservationId
where t1.externBoolean = 1
```

but using lambda expressions

### Answer: With help from suggestions below I ended up with this

#### it contains a bit more than the quesiton, but it Works

```
var model1 = db.Pronestor_Internservice.Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime
(x.booking_start_time) >= startDate && DbFunctions.TruncateTime
(x.booking_end_time) <= endDate && x.reservation_name.Contains(search_text) 
&& x.resource_category_id == 61)
.Join(db.Pronestor_Internservice, x => x.reservation_id, x => 
x.reservation_id, (x, y) => y).ToList
```

Comment: Can you give it a shot first, and then we help where needed?

Comment: I've been giving it shots for 30 minutes.. 
I'm not that good with lamdba and I've been googling all kinda stuff

"join to same table"
"self referencing tables" 

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Joining the same table is no different than joining two different tables. Just use `context.MyTable` twice instead of using `context.Table1` and `context.Table2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Queryable.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534644(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var query = t1.Join(t2, x => x.ReservationId, x => x.ReservationId, (x, y) => new {First = x, Second = y})
    .Where(x => x.First.externBoolean == 1)
    .Select(x => x.Second);
```

Or

```
var query = t1.Where(x => x.externBoolean == 1)
     .Join(t2, x => x.ReservationId, x => x.ReservationId, (x, y) => y);
```

Comment: x indicates row from first table and y indicates row from second table. `(x,y)=>y` is the selector which selects rows from second table.

Comment: but you write the same thing twice.

x => x.ReservationId, x => x.ReservationId

Comment: both of them is specifying condition for join. first one define `ReservationId` as column for first table, second one define it for the second table.

Comment: Marking this is my answer.

The other answers might be right aswell, but I used the alternative version here on my expression, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

For class:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int ReservationId { get; set; }
    public bool ExternBoolean { get; set; }
}
```

you can use this code:

```
List<Reservation> result = reservations
    .Where(r => r.ExternBoolean)
    .Join(reservations, r1 => r1.ReservationId, r2 => r2.ReservationId, (r1, r2) => new { r1, r2 })
    .Select(pair => pair.r2)
    .ToList();
```

r, r1 and r2 is a part of [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

You can read this query from call to call. From source collection `reservations` filter values [where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535040(v=vs.100).aspx) `ExternBoolean` property is true (for each `r` in collection check `r.ExternBoolean`) and [join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534644(v=vs.110).aspx) each filtered object in to all elements of same collection `reservations` (1st parameter) by matching equality of properties.

For each element `r1` of first collection (filtered) get ReservationId property (2nd parameter) and for each element `r2` of second collection `reservations` get ReservationId property (3rd parameter) too.

Then for pairs in two collection where properties matched select new anonymous class with 2 fields `r1` and `r2`.

Next select from this pairs collection for each element `pair` only the second property `r2` (because r2 contains an element r1 that joined with itself).

Finally execute query by iterate it via `ToList()`.

Comment: r, r1 and r2 is a part of lambda expression. I'll update my answer.